# Using phpspec to test two-way relationships that require pass by reference

Tags: phpspec

I'm using phpspec to test my zend 2 module and having issues with testing pass-by-reference. I've read other topics about this that state it's bad design if you are having to do this. I disagree that this a blanket statement.

I need to represent a two-way relationship between classes where two classes have references two each other.

Is there a way for me to get phpspec to test this or is there a better design I need to consider.

Comment: What's the actual behaviour you're trying to test?

Comment: I want to ensure that Class A can return Class B and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to ensure that Class A can return Class B and vice versa.

This is not really a behaviour, but state verification. PhpSpec focuses on behaviour, but what you need to do is still possible:

```php
class ASpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function it_exposes_B(B $b)
    {
        $this->beConstructedWith($b); // or $this->setB($b);

        $this->getB()->shouldReturn($b);
    }
}
```

The BSpec would look similar:

```php
class BSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function it_exposes_A(A $a)
    {
        $this->beConstructedWith($a); // or $this->setA($a);

        $this->getA()->shouldReturn($a);
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work since it should be passed by reference not value. Is there a way to get around this in phpspec?

Comment: Objects in PHP are passed by reference, not by value.

Comment: You can pass by reference using the reference operator (&).  BTW thank you for you responses/replies.